# How to find an index and value of rows specify by column from tables by Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select a value of my table by row and column position as below description.
This tables was used by **appendTo** method to **.tbody** selector and then I've got more rows as below I just show two of rows and each of rows I have **.Open** selector was used for user click to get a value on **column number 4** by current position or index of that row.

Here HTML:

```
<table class"mytable">
    <tbody class="tbody">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>THB-PP-000001</td>
            <td>1005-000001</td>
            <td>100</td> //this is the column id I want to get it
            <td><button type="button" class="open"> Open by Id </button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>THB-PP-000001</td>
            <td>1005-000001</td>
            <td>101</td> //this is the column id I want to get it
            <td><button type="button" class="open"> Open by Id </button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is JS:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open", function () {

    var inde = $("table tbody tr td:nth-child(4)").text();
    console.log(inde);
});
```

Thank for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.parent()` along with `.prev()` to get your required data,

```
$(document).on("click", ".open", function () {
    var inde = $(this).parent("td").prev().text();
    console.log(inde);
});
```

If your html is having a `tbody` as a static node then you could use `.tbody` in the place of `document`.

Comment: @Rajapabhu 
If my rows of table like <td>1</td>
           <td>THB-PP-000001</td>
           <td>101</td> //this is the column id I want to get it
            <td>1005-000001</td> 
            <td>1005-000001</td> 
            <td><button type="button" class="open"> Open by Id </button></td>
How can We user Prev() method?

Comment: It is as crazy or not if I used this var inde = $(this).parent("td").prev().prev().prev().prev().prev().text();?

I will use Prev() Method to find the position of column that I want

Comment: @HengSopheak So you wont have the column in proper order? Is there any pattern for that? Or will it be possible to add a class to that required td?

Comment: OH so with this method I can't user nth-child() or another technique without  add any selector right

Comment: @HengSopheak You can use `nth-child()`, `$(this).parent().siblings("td").filter(":nth-child(4)").text()`